# git push error: error: src refspec <branch_name> does not match any

Tags: git, azure-devops, push

I have VSTS git repository cloned to my local drive in Windows.
After committing the files to local cloned repository, trying to push to remote repository.
But seeing the git below error.

```
git push -u origin <branch_name> ## Where branch_name=remote_branch_name
error: src refspec <branch_name> does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://vsts.server.com/<project_name>/_git/<repository>'
```

However, I could push using below command. The git remote has the origin pointing to remote git repository. 
How to make "git push -u origin branch_name" push to remote repository.

```
$ git push https://vsts.server.com/<project_name>/_git/<repository> local_branch:remote_branch_name
Enumerating objects: 66, done.
Counting objects: 100% (66/66), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (46/46), done.
Writing objects: 100% (63/63), 17.29 KiB | 804.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 63 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Analyzing objects... (63/63) (9 ms)
remote: Storing packfile... done (28 ms)
remote: Storing index... done (34 ms)
To https://vsts.server.com/<project_name>/_git/<repository>   
  22159af..dc0e19e  local_branch -> remote_branch_name
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you ran `git push -u origin <name>`? Did you double check the spelling of that name? Your successful push shows (with your redactions) a *pair* of branch names separated by a colon, which works with or without `-u`, but your failed one shows (with your redactions) a single name, with no colon. Every single character here is important: a single-character typographic error could result in the error you saw.

Comment: You can use `git branch -vv` to see the upstream branch for each local branch (if such exists). In this case it seems you have different names for the local branch and the upstream branch.

Comment: @joran - yes, in the remote, the branch name is like XYZ-123 and local xyz123.                                                                                                               
 $ git branch -vv
  master    dbe744e Added README file
* bug18000  dc0e19e Added module files

$ git branch -a
  master
* bug18000
  remotes/origin/BUG-18000

Comment: @torek - I am using git push -u origin <name> because it has the origin url set for local repository and it just requires remote branch name. This approach is the direct and easy way to push the code once the local and remote has the url set. But since its not working, i google and found the second approach and it worked. Is there a way to specify the local branch and remote branch in git push -u origin command?

Comment: That's not the case: `git push -u` requires, not the *remote* branch name, but rather the *local* branch name. That branch name must also match a remote branch name, if it exists; if not, the presence of the `-u` will *create* that remote branch name and, as a side effect, create a (local) remote-tracking name and set the (local) branch's upstream to the (local) remote-tracking name. (Given your intended usage, I'd recommend simply not using the `-u` option.)

Comment: @torek, I will give a try with local and remote branch same and keep updated. Make sense now.